# Chrome dev tools Network -> Preview tab not rendering html/css anymore, like Firefox does

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, symfony4

Since quite some time ago (probably months) I noticed that Chrome dev tools does not render the html/css correctly anymore. It does render something, but it's not looking great, making it hard to use. This is how it looks in Firefox and how it looked like in Chrome too:

[image]

But currently in chrome it looks like this:

[image]

I know in Firefox the tab is called Response, but if I go there in chrome you just get raw HTML. An option you can switch in the Firefox tab.

I didn't have a lot of errors I had to debug trough the network tab but currently im back to it and starts to get annoying so I checked some Github issues and other pages on internet but I can't find anything similar that might help solve this question. I couldn't find any settings either. Am I doing something wrong?

Im using Chrome: 103.0.5060.66. Symfony version: 4.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because of the improved security on the network preview tab introduced in Chrome 102:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-102/#network-preview

Comment: I see, it also seems like there is no possible fix since they call it "expected behaviour" now... Tnx for the answer! If you ever see a fix/solution, I would be happy to know.

Comment: This is a pain in the backside as reading error messages was a whole lot easier with some colour and spacing. Now I get mumbo jumbo when debugging yuk

Comment: Ridiculous. I guess the Chrome Devs don't spend most of their day debugging POST calls from PHP frameworks! This was done 3.5 years ago and it was rolled back as it caused developers such a headache. Seems they've gone ahead and chucked it back in again without any effort to implement an override. Appreciate there's a security angle to it but ultimately if 'Developer Tools' is not being built with developers in mind, then what's the actual point? For the moment locking at version 101 and hope we get an override option for localhost or something in the future is about all I can think.

Comment: You can install previous version Linux : http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_101.0.4951.64-1_amd64.deb

Unfortunately, I haven't found another OS.

Comment: Have to agree with @Mark on this -- absolutely stupid that Chrome DevTools still has this as an active issue.
My current workaround is using Postman in another window since Chrome refuses to render this content.

I've noticed it will render the preview _sometimes_ for the same resource

Answer (score 4):

It will be back starting from version 106. You can already have it in beta version 106.0.5249.40

Comment: Looking forward to it!